# C++ print alphabet using char type like Excel formula =CHAR(CODE(A1)+1) with value of cell A1 is a

Tags: c++

I'm learning char type, and I'm trying to print alphabet the way like I learnt from Excel, if value of cell A1 is a then cell B1 will be b after using the formula =CHAR(CODE(A1)+1). My code:

```
char test = 'X';
cout<<test+2;
```

Is there a way to make my code print Z instead of 90? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, but it is interesting to understand why it prints 90 (which is the ascii value for Z). The version of `<<` that will be called depends on the type of the operand. `test+2` gets promoted to type `int`, and thus `<<` for int is called. You may force the type back to a char using `static_cast`.

Comment: Because the + operator right?

Comment: What you have right now is the equivalent of `CODE(A1)+1`. You need to convert that ASCII code back into a character with `char(intValue)`

Comment: thank you you guys very much, I just did it: cout<<static_cast<char>(test+2); and also char(test+2), too. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You need to use type casting. Here is the code:

```
char character = 'X';
cout<<char(character +1);
```

The code prints 'Y' instead of 89.